# File uploading category error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a file system which I can upload any types of file. I have 4 categories: music, images, video, documents and text files. My problem is, if I choose music category, the only accepted format is mp3, when images, all kinds of image format but when I choose documents all types of file is appearing on my document. Can you please help me?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: filter.php');
}
else{
    $uname=$_SESSION['username'];
    $desired_dir="user_data/$uname/";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>LADD DMS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />

    <!-- bootstarp -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!--bootstrap-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="home.php">LADD DMS</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>

        </ul>
        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="logout.php" title="Click to logout"><i class="icon-off icon-red"></i><?=$_SESSION['username']?></a>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="mainsection">
        <div class="main">
           <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i><a href="addfile.php">Add File</a></button>
           <hr>
        <div id="container">
        <div class="form_head">Add File Form</div><hr>
            <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="uploader" value="<?=$uname?>" readonly/>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['categ'])){
                    $filter=$_POST['categ'];
                    if($filter=='audio/*'){
                    $filtername="Music";
                    }
                    else if ($filter=='image/*'){
                    $filtername="Images";
                    }
                    else if($filter=='video/*'){
                    $filtername="Videos";
                    }
                    else if($filter=='application/*'){
                    $filtername="Documents";
                    }
                    else{
                    $filtername="Text Files";
                    }
                }
                ?>
                    <label class="control-label">Category</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                    <select name="categ" id="categ" onchange="this.form.submit();" required>
                    <?php 
                    if(!empty($filtername)){ ?>
                        <option value="<?=$filter?>"><?= $filtername?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="audio/*">Music</option>
                        <option value="image/*">Images</option>
                        <option value="video/*">Videos</option>
                        <option value="application/*">Documents</option>
                        <option value="text/*">Text Files</option>
                    </select>
                    </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="addfile.php?cat=<?=$filtername?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Select Files</label>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" accept="<?=$filter?>" multiple required/>
            </div><hr>
             <div class="controls">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="UPLOAD">
                    <a href="home.php" type="reset" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>CANCEL</a>
            </div>
            </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
            $cat_name=$_GET['cat'];
            if($cat_name==""){
                echo "Category Required";
                header('Refresh: 1;url=addfile.php');
            }
            else{
                $count=0;

                foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
                    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
                    $size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
                    $file_f = $size / 1024;
                    $file_size =round($file_f);
                    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
                    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
                    $path="user_data/$uname/$file_name";


                    if($size==0){
                        echo "<h6 style='color:red'>$file_name Exeeds upload limit</h6>";
                    }
                    else{
                        include "db.php";

                        if (file_exists("$desired_dir" . $file_name))
                        {
                            echo "<h6 style='color:red'>".$file_name . " already exists.</h6>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $query="INSERT into upload_data VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type','$cat_name','$uname','$path')";
                            if(mysqli_query($config,$query)){                 
                                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir".$file_name);
                                //echo "<p style='color:blue'>$file_name Uploaded</p";
                                $count=$count+1;
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "Error in adding Files";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "<h6 style='color:blue'>"."$count Files Uploaded<h6>";
                header('Refresh: 2;url=addfile.php');
            }
        }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the `accept` attribute from your file input by your PHP `$filter` variable. PHP is executed on the server. If you want to edit this accept attribute in real time without any refresh (e.g. when the user changes your `categ` select), you need to use *JavaScript*, *jQuery* or something like this.

Another and more secure solution is to check the file extension in PHP (server side) after the form is send. Create an array with your allowed extensions and check it:

```
if($filter=='audio/*'){
    $acceptedFileExtensions = array('mp3');
} else if ($filter=='image/*') {
    $acceptedFileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
} else if($filter=='video/*') {
    $acceptedFileExtensions = array('mp4');
} else if($filter=='application/*') {
    $acceptedFileExtensions = array('pdf');
} else {
    $acceptedFileExtensions = array();
}

$filename = $_FILES['files']['name']
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($extension, $acceptedFileExtensions)) {
    // Extension not allowed
}else {
    // Continue
}
```

Comment: but it works fine on  the category music and images. when i select the category images, it will select only from the computer all the image file type